# How to dynamically change the price of paypal smartbutton according to the PHP cart value?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am not able to assign the value of my shopping cart to the Paypal button in order for the user to be able to pay the correct amount.

The total price of the cart is stored as a variable `$total_price`:

```
<span class="metadata" id="totalprice" value="<?php echo $total_price ?>" > </span>
```

This is done to change it to something callable in Javascript.

Paypal's code from their developer website is as such:

```javascript
<script>
    var num = document.getElementById("totalprice").value;
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: num
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

However by adding my variable as the `value` (as shown in the code above) every time I run the payment, the Paypal pop up briefly opens and then crashes.

I have also tried to create a Javascript variable containing the PHP variable and then setting `value` to that, but it had no effect.

Is there any way to solve this?

EDIT (this is my PHP code)

```javascript
$cart_total=0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $address=obtain_values($connection,$_POST['address']);
    $city=obtain_values($connection,$_POST['city']);
    $pincode=obtain_values($connection,$_POST['pincode']);
    $payment_type=obtain_values($connection,$_POST['payment_type']);
    $user_id=$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val){
        $productArr=get_product($connection,'','',$key);
        $price=$productArr[0]['price'];
        $quantity=$val['qty'];
        $cart_total=$cart_total+($price*$quantity);
        
    }
    $total_price=floatval($cart_total);
    $payment_status='pending';
    if($payment_type=='cod'){
        $payment_status='success';
    }
$order_status='2';
$added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$txnid = substr(hash('', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
    
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO order(user_id,address,city,pincode,payment_type,total_price,payment_status,order_status,added_on,txnid) VALUES('$user_id','$address','$city','$pincode','$payment_type','$total_price','$payment_status','$order_status','$added_on','$txnid')");

$order_id=mysqli_insert_id($connection);

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val){
    $productArr=get_product($connection,'','',$key);
    $price=$productArr[0]['price'];
    $quantity=$val['qty'];
    
    mysqli_query($connection,"insert into `order_detail`(order_id,product_id,qty,price) values('$order_id','$key','$quantity','$price')");
    echo "insert";
}
unset($_SESSION['cart']);


    ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href='thank_you.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}   


?>
```

EDIT 2

```javascript
    <span class="metadata" id="totalprice" value="<?php echo ($total_price) ?>" > </span>
<div class="ht__bradcaump__area" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(images/bg/ali1.png) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ;">
            <div class="ht__bradcaump__wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="bradcaump__inner">
                                <nav class="bradcaump-inner">
                                  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                  <span class="brd-separetor"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"></i></span>
                                  <span class="breadcrumb-item active">checkout</span>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Bradcaump area -->
        <!-- cart-main-area start -->
        <div class="checkout-wrap ptb--100">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="checkout__inner">
                            <div class="accordion-list">
                                <div class="accordion">
                                    
                                    <?php 
                                    $accordion_class='accordion__title';
                                    if(!isset($_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'])){
                                    $accordion_class='accordion__hide';
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="accordion__title">
                                        Checkout Method
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="accordion__body">
                                        <div class="accordion__body__form">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="checkout-method__login">
                                                        <form id="login-form" method="post">
                                                            <h5 class="checkout-method__title">Login</h5>
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Your Email*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="login_email_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="Your Password*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="login_password_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <p class="require">* Required fields</p>
                                                            <div class="dark-btn">
                                                                <button type="button" class="fv-btn" onclick="user_login()">Login</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-output login_msg">
                                                                <p class="form-messege field_error"></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="checkout-method__login">
                                                        <form action="#">
                                                            <h5 class="checkout-method__title">Register</h5>
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="name_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="email_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="mobile_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password*" style="width:100%">
                                                                <span class="field_error" id="password_error"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="dark-btn">
                                                                <button type="button" class="fv-btn" onclick="user_register()">Register</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="<?php echo $accordion_class?>">
                                        Address Information
                                    </div>
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <div class="accordion__body">
                                            <div class="bilinfo">
                                                
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Street Address" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City/State" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="single-input">
                                                                <input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Post code/ zip" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="<?php echo $accordion_class?>">
                                            payment information
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="accordion__body">
                                            <div class="paymentinfo">
                                                <div class="single-method">
                                                    COD <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="COD" required/>
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;PayPal <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="paypal" onclick="showButton()" required/>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                               <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
                                                <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

                                                <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
                                                <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ASCkJmx1-2CeTlk1ABMrnC4xJbalWvyLbv-mIx76k9644aZb49wX82Qrgcn6W15Y3Yvm6GrrfpehN_ib&currency=USD"></script>
                                                        <script>
                                                         document.getElementById("paypal-button-container").style.display = "none";
                                                        function showButton() {
                                                          var x = document.getElementById("paypal-button-container");
                                                          if (x.style.display === "none") {
                                                            x.style.display = "block";
                                                          } else {
                                                            x.style.display = "none";
                                                          }
                                                        }
                                                        </script>
                                                
                                                <script>
                                                
var num = document.getElementById("totalprice").value;                                                    
                                                    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
                                                    paypal.Buttons({

                                                        // Set up the transaction
                                                        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                                                            return actions.order.create({
                                                                purchase_units: [{
                                                                    amount: {
                                                                        value: num
                                                                    }
                                                                }]
                                                            });
                                                        },

                                                        // Finalize the transaction
                                                        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                                                            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                                                                // Show a success message to the buyer
                                                                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                                                            });
                                                        }


                                                    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                                                </script>
                                                <div class="single-method">
                                                  
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                         <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="order-details">
                            <h5 class="order-details__title">Your Order</h5>
                            <div class="order-details__item">
                                <?php
                                $cart_total=0;
                                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val){
                                $productArr=get_product($connection,'','',$key);
                                $pname=$productArr[0]['name'];
                                $mrp=$productArr[0]['mrp'];
                                $price=$productArr[0]['price'];
                                $image=$productArr[0]['image'];
                                $quantity=$val['qty'];
                                $cart_total=$cart_total+($price*$quantity);
                                ?>
                                <div class="single-item">
                                    <div class="single-item__thumb">
                                        <img src="media/product/<?php echo $image?>"  />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-item__content">
                                        <a href="#"><?php echo $pname?></a>
                                        <span class="price"><?php echo $price*$quantity?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-item__remove">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="manage_cart('<?php echo $key?>','remove')"><i class="icon-trash icons"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ordre-details__total">
                                <h5>Order total</h5>
                                <span class="price"><?php echo $cart_total?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                                
<?php require('footer.php')?>
```

Comment: Your ideas aren't far off from what should work, so what is the content of this `$total_price`  ? Perhaps it is invalid. If you look at your JavaScript console when it loads, or the rendered HTML in your browser, both should shed some light as to why it's not working

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your reply. I tried looking at my console but it does not seem to monitor anything. I have put the js variable in the watch section but nothing seems to take place. I also tried setting $total_price to a numerical value to make sure that it was not a data type problem but to no avail. What is it you propose I should do with the rendered HTML? Sorry I am a bit of newbie in web design.

Comment: Save the from your browser and add the relevant div/span/script portion (rendered by PHP) to the end of your question. We can't help without seeing the result of your code running and looking at why it errors.

Comment: Done. Hope I got everything

Comment: Uh that's just more of your PHP. We need you to load the button page in your browser and use "view source" or inspect to get the HTML.

Comment: Ok, I think this time I have finally done it :)

Comment: Seems your PHP is not actually running on your server *at all*, if `<?php ...?>` tags are showing up in the browser.... so, you need a server with a working PHP installation?  Or you shared the wrong thing again

Comment: I shared the wrong thing again. If I Inspect the web page in my browser I don't see any js or php

Comment: The JS will be there in the script tags. Save the page.